# How can I find the domain of this sqrt log function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Can someone help me to find the domain of this function step by steps,
> I know how to find the domain for a log by making it >0 but I am unsure about the process doing it with 2 different logarithm and a square root.
> $$f(x)=\sqrt{\log_{0.5}(5-x)+\log_2(2x-4)-1}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Think about when $\log_{0.5}(5-x)+\log_2(2x-4)-1\ge0$

Comment: You'll have $3$ inequations to solve. Two of these to assure that the arguments of both logs are greater than $0$, for example($5-x>0$). And one to assure yourself that le quantity under the square sign is $<=0$. To do this, you should write both logs in the same basis using the change of basis formula.

Comment: @BernardMassé You meant to say that the quantity under the radical must be $\geq0$

Comment: @ saulspatz. Of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first define both the $\log$s, input of $\log$ should be a positive quantity.

$5 - x > 0 \implies x \in (-\infty, 5)$

---

$2x - 4 > 0 \implies x \in (2, \infty)$

---

Now we know that $\log_{a}{b} = -\log_{\frac{1}{a}}{b} = \log_{\frac{1}{a}}{\frac{1}{b}}$

$\implies\log_{0.5}(5-x) = \log_{2}{\frac{1}{5-x}}$

Now, we know that anything inside square root should be non negative.

$\implies \log_{0.5}(5-x)+\log_2(2x-4)-1 \geq 0$

$\implies \log_{2}{\frac{1}{5-x}+\log_2(2x-4)-1} \geq 0$

$\implies \log_2{\frac{2x-4}{5-x}} \geq 1$

$\implies \frac{2x-4}{5-x} \geq 2$

$\implies \frac{2x-4}{5-x} - 2 \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{4x-14}{5-x} \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{4x-14}{x-5} \leq 0$

$\implies x \in [\frac72, 5)$

---

**Taking intersection of all 3 intervals:**

**$$\boxed{x \in [\frac72,5)}$$**

Comment: Now we know that "" "", is that a formula ?

Comment: @yass $\log_ab = \frac{\log b}{\log a} = \frac{\log b}{-\log(a^{-1})} = \frac{\log b}{-\log\frac{1}{a}} = \frac{-\log b}{\log\frac{1}{a}} =  \frac{\log \frac{1}{b}}{\log\frac{1}{a}} = \log_{\frac{1}{a}}\frac{1}{b}$ This is the full working, this is very useful at places